# не работает visual studio 2022 и 2019

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10

у меня все работало нормально. На следующий день у меня разом перестали работать обе среды visual studio 2022 Preview, 2019. помогите решить проблему!

[image: Вот ошибка при запуске:]

Я делал sxstrace и вот логи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот devenv.exe.config:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так вы посмотрите, что у вас в том конфиге `devenv.exe.Config`, на который оно ругается. Может там правда битый `XML`.

Comment: А что делать если он битый?

Comment: Варианты: 1) Попробовать починить XML вручную 2) Попробовать удалить/переименовать файл 3) Переустановить студию

Comment: 2 я делал(не помогло), 3 я не хочу интернета нет

Comment: и как сделать 1

Comment: А что в файле, как он выглядит? Откройте его чем-нибудь посмотреть как текст

Comment: посмотрите на вопрос, я прикрепил фото файла

Comment: Ну у вас реально битый XML, это должен быть текстовый файл особой структуры, а у вас какие-то обрывки бинарника. Проверьте диск на всякий случай, возможно у вас сбой файловой системы, а может и диск сыпется.